# what is the %2F issue with service worker

Tags: javascript, html, http, spring-boot, service-worker

I'm my webapp, The search url looks something like this.

```
http://localhost:8080/search/{value}/page/1
```

And if I provide the search value with a forward slash such as `some/value`, The actual url goes to my spring boot app as

```
http://localhost:8080/search/some/value/page/1
```

Due to the extra Forward slashes being treated as path, The controller returns 404.

So I made the search value url safe by,

```
$('.search').submit(function (ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var searchParam = ev.target.search.value;
  if (searchParam) {
    window.location.href = '/search/' + encodeURIComponent(searchParam) + '/page/1';
  }
});
```

and the URL became something like this. Which was working so far.

```
http://localhost:8080/search/some%2Fvalue/page/1
```

### But then came the actual problem.

I implemented a `ServiceWorker` for offline support as guided [here](https://css-tricks.com/serviceworker-for-offline/) and now my `ServiceWorker` gives `HTTP 400` for any URL that has a `%2F`. In my case the above search URL. 
[image: Screenshot of the error]
I searched google for a reason and the only trace i could get was a single line at the end [this article](https://alf.nu/ServiceWorker) which I quote,

> Google fixed the %2F issue, but recommends every site using sandbox
>   domains add extra code to protect against this.

This makes me curious to know the following.

- **What is the `%2F` issue?**
- **What piece of code google was talking about?**

> Just to clarify my intention of this question,
>
> - I can avoid the issue by completely stripping all the Forward slashes from the search value in the UI itself. **(which is what I'm planning to do.)**
> - Search based on query params is not an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

`%2f` is a [URL encoded](https://www.urldecoder.org/) `/`. It looks like there may be a bug in your routing code, as the URL `/` is likely getting set to `%2f` in your `encodeURIComponent(searchParam)` method. The service worker is not properly un-encoding it.

As a workaround you may want to use `searchParam.split('/')` then encode each string individually. Finally, `result.join('/')` to get your proper URL

Comment: routing code in spring-boot? I have no routing code in spring boot or my service worker. The 400 came straight from Service worker. See screenshot.

Comment: As in the code where you set the route here: `window.location.href = '/search/' + encodeURIComponent(searchParam) + '/page/1';`

Comment: I know that the encodeURIComponent is giving %2f while converting a slash. The problem was that the 400 was coming from spring boot... Its been a problem since a while for PathParams which has %2f in their content... See my answer....